# How to solve error messsage about neo4j ：Invalid input 'UNIQUE'

Tags: neo4j, unique

I try to execute this comnands, but screen show the message:  How to solve this problems?

```
Invalid input 'UNIQUE': expected "(", "allShortestPaths" or "shortestPath" (line 4, column 8 (offset: 269))
"CREATE UNIQUE(s1)<-[:FROM]->(r)"
```

initial input comnand:

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
load csv with headers from "https://lovecandyhsu.neocities.org/relations.csv" as csvLine
MATCH (s1:Station { id: toInteger(csvLine.fromId)}),(r:Route { id: toInt(csvLine.route_informationId)}),(s2:Station { id: toInt(csvLine.toId)})
CREATE UNIQUE(s1)<-[:FROM]->(r)
CREATE UNIQUE(r)<-[:TO]->(s2)
RETURN csvLine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Neo4j ? `CREATE UNIQUE` is no longer available is later versions. Use `MERGE` instead
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/

You could try,

```
...MERGE (s1)<-[:FROM]-(r) MERGE (r)<-[:TO]->(s2)...
```